# Python3 Function to find sum of primes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function (say, sum_primes) in python3 that takes in a number and returns the sum of all primes less than or equal to that number.

I tried like:

```
def sum_primes(num):
    total = 0
    for i in range(2, num+1):
        if num%i == 0:
            break 
        else:
            total += i
        return total
sum_primes(11)
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: why do you break out of the loop once you have not found a prime

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:

```
#Take the input from user
upto = int(input("Find sum of prime numbers up to : "))

sum = 0

for num in range(2, upto + 1):

i = 2

for i in range(2, num):
    if (int(num % i) == 0):
        i = num
        break;

#If the number is prime then add it.
if i is not num:
    sum += num

print("\nSum of all prime numbers upto", upto, ":", sum)
```